# WATIR - Setting a checkbox without accessing it directly

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using Watir to automate some web chore and I need to set a checkbox which is located as the previous tag of the parent of a div with some known text.

HTML looks like

```
<div>
 ...
 <input type='checkbox'>
 <div>
  <div class='text'>text I know</div>
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to locate the checkbox with

```
browser.div(class: 'text', text: /text I know/).parent.preceding_sibling
```

As evidence of that, if I run `puts browser.div(class: 'text', text: /text I know/).parent.preceding_sibling/.html` I get `"<input type=\"checkbox\">"`.

However, if I try

```
browser.div(class: 'text', text: /text I know/).parent.preceding_sibling.set
```

Which, [as far as I know](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/CheckBox#set-instance_method), is the way to set checkboxes with Watir, I get

`method_missing': undefined method`set' for # (NoMethodError)

Why do I get a `Watir::HTMLElement` and not a `Watir::CheckBox` instance?
Is there a way to get a checkbox instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, the following code returns element object

```
browser.div(class: 'text', text: /text I know/).parent.preceding_sibling
```

So set method is not defined for that object. set method is defined for CheckBox class. So you try the following code, it will work for you.

```
browser.div(class: 'text', text: /text I know/).parent.preceding_sibling.to_subtype.set
```

`to_subtype` returns the corresponding object for that tag. So your set method would work.